# Blank screen first time launching app xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, warnings, view-hierarchy

I am having a little issue with logging into an app the first time with a blank screen and I am getting the warning "Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" After I close and relaunch, the views appear fine. I believe it has something to do with the `rootViewController` but not sure... Thanks in advance for any help or direction!

**App delegate**

```
    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?
        var ref:FIRDatabaseReference?
        var databaseHandle:FIRDatabaseHandle?

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

            window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            window?.rootViewController = MainNavigationController()

            FIRApp.configure()
            ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

            return true
        }
```

**Navigation controller as** `rootViewController`

```
    class MainNavigationController: UINavigationController {

        var segmentedController: UISegmentedControl!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let vc1 = TravelersFeedVC()
            let vc2 = ProfileVC()

            if isLoggedIn() {
                // assume user is logged in
                let homeController = HomeController()
                viewControllers = [homeController]
                homeController.firstViewController = vc1
                homeController.secondViewController = vc2


            } else {
                perform(#selector(showLoginController), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.01)
            }
        }

        fileprivate func isLoggedIn() ->  Bool {
            return UserDefaults.standard.isLoggedIn()
        }

        func showLoginController() {
            let loginController = LoginController()
            present(loginController, animated: true, completion: {
                // perhaps do something here later
            })
        }
    }
```

// log in function called

```
    func finishLoggingIn() {
        let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        guard let mainNavigationController = rootViewController as? MainNavigationController else { return }

        let vc1 = TravelersFeedVC()
        let vc2 = ProfileVC()

        if isLoggedIn() {
            // assume user is logged in
            let homeController = HomeController()
            mainNavigationController.viewControllers = [HomeController()]
            homeController.firstViewController = vc1
            homeController.secondViewController = vc2

        } else {
            perform(#selector(showLoginController), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.01)
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: true)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Calling presentViewController presents the view controller modally, outside the existing navigation stack; it is not contained by your UINavigationController or any other. So please push views in your navigation the first time or every time you enter the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so my last answer was wrong (i deleted it), the things is that in app there is a keywindow, which is your navcontroller, and you cannot present anything on this one untill it will load its subviews (even if it hasn't any), and that would happend on viewdidappear, so you should put your code from viewdidload there.